# Is it possible to force a target override when starting a MergeRequest on Gitlab?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution

I am trying to implement a CI pipeline where `development` is merged to a release branch which, in turn, is merged to `master`.

The release branches are named `x.y.z` and reflect the version number of the release.

The release job modifies the pom to create a SNAPSHOT version (using the branch name). The master job modifies the pom to create a release version by removing '-SNAPSHOT'. Both jobs commit and push their changes.

The downside is that this causes a conflict on the next iteration. The previous commit on `master` puts it out-of-sync with `development` and the MergeRequest flags a conflict. The only difference is the version number in the pom and is straightforward to fix.

[image: Gitlab repository graph]

In the diagram above, it is not possible to merge `1.0.1` with `master` because of the commit 'Create release version (1.0.0)'.

I am wondering if it is possible (in Gitlab) to force an override when merging. Can I force an override of "theirs" with "mine" within the MergeRequest?

*Background*

- This CI process seems to give a solution to the problem of who sets the pom version? This way the release branch defines the version and SNAPSHOTs and Releases are defined by the target branches.
- This is for a web application and I want WAR files to be stored in Nexus as releases or SNAPSHOTs

Answer (score 1):

GitLab has an interactive editor for solving merge conflicts:

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/resolve_conflicts.html

It is possible to click `use this` on either their changes or our changes. There is a quirk with this though: The conflict resolution will be in the source branch and not in the target branch. This means that if you merge `1.0.1` into `master` and there's a conflict, it will show up as a merge of `master` into `1.0.1`! It is then possible to accept the merge request, and this will result in a merge of `1.0.1` into `master`. This is a bit unexpected, but it makes it possible for a branch author to fix conflicts, even if they are not allowed to push fixes to the target branch.

There is an issue for this on GitLab:

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/issues/25014

But they write that they don't have any plans to move forward with that at the moment.